# Angular share the data between nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing issue related to nested **ng-repeat** structure.

My sample HTML is given below.

I want to find out the number of **`<tr id="thirdNg">`** rows (**number_of_thirdNg_row**) after applying filter to parent3 ng-repeat  **`<tr id="thirdNg">`**and
get that counts in  the **`<tr  id="firstNg">`** rows to hide/show
the  **`<tr  id="firstNg">`**  rows depend on  zero or non-zero count
 
of **`<tr id="thirdNg">`** row. How I cant get that **number_of_thirdNg_row** count?

`<input ng-model="modelFrmTextField">
    <table class="table table-bordered" >
        <thead>
            <tr >

                <th>Search Results</th> 
            </tr>
            ......
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-show="number_thirdNg_row" ng-repeat="child1 in parent1" id="firstNg"> // number of "firstNg" row 
                <td class="word-break">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="child2 in parent2" id="secNg"> // number of "secNg" row
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody> 
                                            <tr  ng-repeat="child3 in  parent3 | filter : modelFrmTextField" id="thirdNg">  // number of "thirdNg" row
                                                <td></td>
                                                ................ 
                                            </tr> 
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>`

Comment: Isnt `number_thirdNg_row`  equal to `parent3.length`? (assuming `parent3` is an array, which it seems to be, from reading your markup)

Comment: Assume thats true "number_thirdNg_row" equal to parent3.length" but how I will get that "number_thirdNg_row" after applying filter to parent3   "ng-repeat" row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $index property in ng-repeat to find your current index :

see this [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#example) extracted from the official angular documentation

I hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$index` parameter owned by sending it to its function or use wherever example:

```
<td ng-click="click($index)"></td>
```

Documentation : [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)